# Amazon App Store - Location of the downloaded APK

Tags: apk, amazon-appstore

Where does this app store save the downloaded APK file? I have a problem where certain apps will only install when the sdcard is unmounted. The Amazon App store needs sdcard to be mounted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is based on my EVO, but they appear to download into the Appstore's "private" external storage directory, which is `/sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezia/cache/`. From what I've seen they appear to then get deleted after being installed, but anything which has been downloaded and not installed looks to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer [@eldarerathis](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/981/eldarerathis)!

Looks like it might have changed slightly since then. On my Motorola Bionic I found the apk files `/sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezia/files/apks`.

An update to one of my apps would download in the Amazon appstore but wouldn't install for whatever reason. So I clicked "download" in the app store, then immediately opened ESFile explorer, found the apk, waited for it to finish downloading (clicking "refresh" once in a while). Then I just clicked the apk there and it installed perfectly. Woot!