# Where does Amazon App Store keep the APKs

Tags: amazon-appstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Amazon App Store - Location of the downloaded APK](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10336/amazon-app-store-location-of-the-downloaded-apk)

I am trying to find an APK that I downloaded from the Amazon app store but it is nowhere to be found. I have looked in all the normal APK locations but none of the APKs from the Amazon app store are there. Does anyone know where they are hidden?

Comment: Never knew that Amazon's apks are located somewhere else then common ones... interesting!

Comment: @barmaley They're in the same spot when installed, but Amazon has a different folder to download them to than the Market does.

Answer (score 0):

they are on the SD card.

The free ones are put here. (I would assume they all get put in the same spot.)

```
/sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezia/cache
```

Their names are by no means associated with the app though.