# Amazon Underground APK download location?

Tags: apk, amazon-underground

I am trying to download a game for my child in the Amazon Underground app store.

The problem is, the Underground app refuses to install under my child's login (it claims to be incompatible with my device!?!).  I can install both the Underground app and the particular app I want to install under *my* login, but I don't allow my child to know my PIN or use my login as I have other things install I don't want her to mess with.

If I could find the APK before it is installed I figured I could just manually install it under my child's login, but I can't find it!  I have run a file manager and did a search under the entire filesystem (as root, no less!) for all files within the last hour, and did not find *any* APKs.  Some other answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18989/where-are-the-downloads-from-the-amazon-appstore-stored) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10336/amazon-app-store-location-of-the-downloaded-apk) claim it is stored in `/sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezia/cache/` or `/sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezia/files/apks`.  However, both of those directories are empty after the download is finished.  I am looking when it tells me the download is ready to install, but before I allow it to install, so I know the APK must be around there somewhere.  Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

Look in `/data/data/com.amazon.mShop.android/files`

I had to use Fx to search my entire device to find the Amazon Video APK.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look there when I get home.  I've got Fx too and used it to search but it didn't find the APK but... guess we will see what's there.

Comment: You're welcome.  It has moved around.  I used to be about to find them under the Venezia directory.

Comment: Looking from the path, I believe you need your device to be rooted to access the internal storage `/data/data/..`. OP didn't mention anything about their device, just a precaution though...

Answer (score 0):

The smaller size apps are located in `/data/data/uk.amazon.mShop.android/files/` and are named `update.......` - you must be root to see/extract these.

The larger size apps or games are located `/sdcard/apks/` as they are too big to store in the apps private /data/data directory and are also named `update....` - a stock user can see/extract these.

This was correct at time of posting as the location has changed i nthe past, it may well change again.